# Optimal binary search tree is only optimal for a specific order of pairs of key and frequency?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, dynamic-programming

Providing pairs of a key and its frequency,

```
a 32
an 7
and 69
by 13
effects 6
for 15
from t 0
high 8
in 64
of t 42
on 22
the 79
to 18
with 9
```

we can build a [optimal BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree) by [Knuth's dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree#Knuth's_dynamic_programming_algorithm).

We can build another optimal BST if we shuffle the pairs.

So optimal BST is only optimal for a specific order of pairs, right? If it is, what's the scene we can apply this data structure for?

Comment: If BST is height balanced, it is optimal for all orders of pairs.

Comment: Apparently it can't ensure that height is balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> So optimal BST is only optimal for a specific order of pairs, right?

That's what the Wikipedia article says:

> ... is a binary search tree which provides the smallest possible search time (or expected search time) for a given sequence of accesses (or access probabilities).

In other words, if you change the frequencies of the individual words, you will by necessity change the order of keys in the tree.

You also asked:

> If it is, what's the scene we can apply this data structure for?

You can use it like any binary search tree. The idea here is that it arranges the tree such that frequently searched items require fewer nodes to be searched, at the expense of infrequently accessed items, which require more searches. It outperforms a general binary search tree (including balanced trees) when the access probabilities of the individual items vary greatly.

Although you can have a dynamic optimal BST, re-shaping the tree can get expensive if you have a lot of modifications. The best application of this is when the tree is static, or if the tree has orders of magnitude more queries than modifications.

Answer (score 0):

An optimal BST is a BST, and a BST has a sorted order, so you can look up the word no matter what it is. So yes, optimal BST is only optimal for a specific order of pairs.

It's can be used as a dictionary just like a BST.